# Azure Search - There were not enough free threads in the ThreadPool to complete the operation

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

We have a free tier plan of Azure Cognitive Search with one datasource(Cosmos DB), one indexer and one index.

The indexer is scheduled to run every hour, but its been frequently failing with **"There were not enough free threads in the ThreadPool to complete the operation"** error message.

Sometimes it successfully runs after a failure without any changes on the datasource or configuration.

Searching through the docs we didn't found any specific quota related to indexer runs.

So, our question: Is this a free tier quota, a service error or something else?

[execution results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ra5pG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome, Luiz.

Remember that the Free tier is only useful for basic tests and for getting the general idea of how Azure cognitive search works. You have strong limitations of only 50 MB of storage capacity, no parallel instances and no scaling at all.
I had the same issue than you and what I did was to move to the next tier, the Basic one in which you have more decent constraints like 2 GB of storage, paralellization up to 3 replicas and 15 indexes and indexers. In my case, worked fine.
Cost of Basic tier would be 99% of times under 100$ / month.

Comment: Thank you. That is my suspicion as well, but I was trying to get a confirmation of sorts, since this error/limit isn't described anywhere. I'll keep the question open for a few more days to see if someone has any specifics.

Comment: Luiz, this is an unexpected error that the Azure Cognitive Search engineering team is currently investigating. Even if it is expected due to you being on free tier, it should be being surfaced to you in a more user friendly way, so thanks for reporting this and we will be working on a fix in the coming weeks. Feel free to file a support case for more detailed updates/explanations.

Comment: @CareyHalton thank you for letting us know and I'll be looking forward for the fix.